# Netbeans 7.1.1 very long deploy times to Glassfish 3.1.2?

Tags: netbeans, ubuntu, glassfish

Is it normal that it takes about 2-3 minutes to deploy an Enterprise Application with one EJB consisting of two session beans to Glassfish 3.1.2 from Netbeans 7.1.1 (right-click EE-app and selecting "deploy") ? What can I do to speed up this process ?

I am using JDK 1.6.0_30 and the Glassfish is running on a remote machine (already tried Ubuntu 10.04 and 11.10) on my LAN. With Windows 7 as host for Glassfish it's no problem (pressing 'deploy' in Netbeans takes approx. 5 seconds until sucessfully deployed).

Any help highly appreciated! Many thanks in advance!

```
[#|2012-04-23T16:25:58.883+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.eclipse.persistence.session.file:/home/nicolas/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/LawSuiteEE/LawSuiteEE-ejb_jar/_LawSuiteEE-ejbPU|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461|#]

[#|2012-04-23T16:25:58.885+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.eclipse.persistence.session.file:/home/nicolas/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/LawSuiteEE/LawSuiteEE-ejb_jar/_LawSuiteEE-ejbPU|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|file:/home/nicolas/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/LawSuiteEE/LawSuiteEE-ejb_jar/_LawSuiteEE-ejbPU login successful|#]

[#|2012-04-23T16:25:58.885+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|org.eclipse.persistence.session.file:/home/nicolas/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/LawSuiteEE/LawSuiteEE-ejb_jar/_LawSuiteEE-ejbPU.server|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Multiple [2] JMX MBeanServer instances exist, we will use the server at index [0] : [com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.DynamicInterceptor@50d420eb].|#]

[#|2012-04-23T16:25:58.885+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|org.eclipse.persistence.session.file:/home/nicolas/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/LawSuiteEE/LawSuiteEE-ejb_jar/_LawSuiteEE-ejbPU.server|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|JMX MBeanServer in use: [com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.DynamicInterceptor@50d420eb] from index [0] |#]

[#|2012-04-23T16:25:58.886+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|org.eclipse.persistence.session.file:/home/nicolas/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/LawSuiteEE/LawSuiteEE-ejb_jar/_LawSuiteEE-ejbPU.server|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|JMX MBeanServer in use: [com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer@6e22f51b] from index [1] |#]

[#|2012-04-23T16:25:58.966+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers.builder|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|TopLevel AvailabilityService.getAvailabilityEnabled => true|#]

[#|2012-04-23T16:25:58.967+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers.builder|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|TopLevel EjbAvailabilityService.getAvailabilityEnabled => true|#]

[#|2012-04-23T16:25:58.967+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers.builder|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|**Global AvailabilityEnabled => true; isAppHAEnabled: false|#]

[#|2012-04-23T16:25:58.967+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers.builder|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|StatefulContainerBuilder AvailabilityEnabled for this app => false|#]

[#|2012-04-23T16:25:58.967+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers.builder|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|StatefulContainerBuilder.buildStoreManager() storeName: StatefulBean-87503047946600448-BackingStore|#]

[#|2012-04-23T16:25:58.968+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.file.FileBackingStore|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|[FileBackingStore::initialize] Successfully Created and initialized store. Working dir: /home/nicolas/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/session-store/StatefulBean-87503047946600448; Configuration: BackingStoreConfiguration{clusterName='null', instanceName='null', storeName='StatefulBean-87503047946600448-BackingStore', shortUniqueName='87503047946600448', storeType='file', maxIdleTimeInSeconds=-1, relaxVersionCheck='null', maxLoadWaitTimeInSeconds=0, baseDirectoryName='/home/nicolas/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/session-store/StatefulBean-87503047946600448', keyClazz=interface java.io.Serializable, valueClazz=class org.glassfish.ha.store.util.SimpleMetadata, synchronousSave=false, typicalPayloadSizeInKiloBytes=0, vendorSpecificSettings={start.gms=false, async.replication=true, key.transformer=com.sun.ejb.base.sfsb.util.SimpleKeyGenerator@75e1c7c0, local.caching=true, value.class.is.thread.safe=true, broadcast.remove.expired=false}}|#]

[#|2012-04-23T16:25:58.968+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers.builder|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|StatefulContainerbuilder instantiated store: org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.file.FileBackingStore@3a014ab6; ha-enabled: false ==> BackingStoreConfiguration{clusterName='null', instanceName='null', storeName='StatefulBean-87503047946600448-BackingStore', shortUniqueName='87503047946600448', storeType='file', maxIdleTimeInSeconds=-1, relaxVersionCheck='null', maxLoadWaitTimeInSeconds=0, baseDirectoryName='/home/nicolas/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/session-store/StatefulBean-87503047946600448', keyClazz=interface java.io.Serializable, valueClazz=class org.glassfish.ha.store.util.SimpleMetadata, synchronousSave=false, typicalPayloadSizeInKiloBytes=0, vendorSpecificSettings={start.gms=false, async.replication=true, key.transformer=com.sun.ejb.base.sfsb.util.SimpleKeyGenerator@75e1c7c0, local.caching=true, value.class.is.thread.safe=true, broadcast.remove.expired=false}}|#]

[#|2012-04-23T16:25:58.998+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB StatefulBean: [java:global/LawSuiteEE/LawSuiteEE-ejb/StatefulBean, java:global/LawSuiteEE/LawSuiteEE-ejb/StatefulBean!ch.lawsuite.services.StatefulBeanRemote]|#]

[#|2012-04-23T16:25:58.998+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|EJB5182:Glassfish-specific (Non-portable) JNDI names for EJB StatefulBean: [ch.lawsuite.services.StatefulBeanRemote#ch.lawsuite.services.StatefulBeanRemote, ch.lawsuite.services.StatefulBeanRemote]|#]

[#|2012-04-23T16:25:59.054+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB UserFacade: [java:global/LawSuiteEE/LawSuiteEE-ejb/UserFacade, java:global/LawSuiteEE/LawSuiteEE-ejb/UserFacade!ch.lawsuite.control.UserFacadeRemote]|#]

[#|2012-04-23T16:25:59.054+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|EJB5182:Glassfish-specific (Non-portable) JNDI names for EJB UserFacade: [ch.lawsuite.control.UserFacadeRemote, ch.lawsuite.control.UserFacadeRemote#ch.lawsuite.control.UserFacadeRemote]|#]

[#|2012-04-23T16:25:59.100+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB StatelessBean: [java:global/LawSuiteEE/LawSuiteEE-ejb/StatelessBean!ch.lawsuite.services.StatelessBeanRemote, java:global/LawSuiteEE/LawSuiteEE-ejb/StatelessBean]|#]

[#|2012-04-23T16:25:59.100+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|EJB5182:Glassfish-specific (Non-portable) JNDI names for EJB StatelessBean: [ch.lawsuite.services.StatelessBeanRemote, ch.lawsuite.services.StatelessBeanRemote#ch.lawsuite.services.StatelessBeanRemote]|#]

[#|2012-04-23T16:25:59.115+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB UpdateService: [java:global/LawSuiteEE/LawSuiteEE-ejb/UpdateService, java:global/LawSuiteEE/LawSuiteEE-ejb/UpdateService!ch.lawsuite.services.UpdateService]|#]

[#|2012-04-23T16:25:59.307+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.org.glassfish.deployment.admin|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|LawSuiteEE was successfully deployed in 526 milliseconds.|#]

[#|2012-04-23T16:59:54.449+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.com.sun.enterprise.container.common|_ThreadID=30;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|User [] from host localhost does not have administration access|#]

[#|2012-04-23T16:59:54.456+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.admingui|_ThreadID=19;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|RestResponse.getResponse() gives FAILURE.  endpoint = 'https://localhost:4848/management/domain/servers/server/server'; attrs = '{}'|#]

[#|2012-04-23T16:59:54.456+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.admingui|_ThreadID=19;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Exception Occurred :java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid user name or password.|#]

[#|2012-04-23T16:59:54.495+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.com.sun.enterprise.container.common|_ThreadID=18;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|User [] from host localhost does not have administration access|#]

[#|2012-04-23T16:59:54.548+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.catalina.connector.Request|_ThreadID=20;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|PWC4011: Unable to set request character encoding to UTF-8 from context , because request parameters have already been read, or ServletRequest.getReader() has already been called|#]

[#|2012-04-23T16:59:54.575+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.com.sun.enterprise.container.common|_ThreadID=30;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|User [] from host localhost does not have administration access|#]

[#|2012-04-23T16:59:54.588+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.catalina.connector.Request|_ThreadID=19;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|PWC4011: Unable to set request character encoding to UTF-8 from context , because request parameters have already been read, or ServletRequest.getReader() has already been called|#]

[#|2012-04-23T16:59:54.609+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.com.sun.enterprise.container.common|_ThreadID=20;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|User [] from host localhost does not have administration access|#]

[#|2012-04-23T16:59:54.621+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.catalina.connector.Request|_ThreadID=18;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|PWC4011: Unable to set request character encoding to UTF-8 from context , because request parameters have already been read, or ServletRequest.getReader() has already been called|#]

[#|2012-04-23T16:59:54.637+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.catalina.connector.Request|_ThreadID=21;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|PWC4011: Unable to set request character encoding to UTF-8 from context , because request parameters have already been read, or ServletRequest.getReader() has already been called|#]

[#|2012-04-23T16:59:54.653+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.catalina.connector.Request|_ThreadID=30;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|PWC4011: Unable to set request character encoding to UTF-8 from context , because request parameters have already been read, or ServletRequest.getReader() has already been called|#]

[#|2012-04-23T17:00:00.675+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.admingui|_ThreadID=31;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Redirecting to /common/appServer/serverInstGeneralPe.jsf|#]

[#|2012-04-23T17:00:00.702+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.admingui|_ThreadID=18;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Admin Console: Initializing Session Attributes...|#]

[#|2012-04-23T17:03:41.290+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.eclipse.persistence.session.file:/home/nicolas/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/LawSuiteEE/LawSuiteEE-ejb_jar/_LawSuiteEE-ejbPU|_ThreadID=20;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|file:/home/nicolas/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/LawSuiteEE/LawSuiteEE-ejb_jar/_LawSuiteEE-ejbPU logout successful|#]

[#|2012-04-23T17:04:51.864+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.eclipse.persistence.session.file:/home/nicolas/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/LawSuiteEE/LawSuiteEE-ejb_jar/_LawSuiteEE-ejbPU|_ThreadID=32;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461|#]

[#|2012-04-23T17:04:51.866+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.eclipse.persistence.session.file:/home/nicolas/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/LawSuiteEE/LawSuiteEE-ejb_jar/_LawSuiteEE-ejbPU|_ThreadID=32;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|file:/home/nicolas/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/LawSuiteEE/LawSuiteEE-ejb_jar/_LawSuiteEE-ejbPU login successful|#]

[#|2012-04-23T17:04:51.867+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|org.eclipse.persistence.session.file:/home/nicolas/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/LawSuiteEE/LawSuiteEE-ejb_jar/_LawSuiteEE-ejbPU.server|_ThreadID=32;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Multiple [2] JMX MBeanServer instances exist, we will use the server at index [0] : [com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.DynamicInterceptor@50d420eb].|#]

[#|2012-04-23T17:04:51.867+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|org.eclipse.persistence.session.file:/home/nicolas/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/LawSuiteEE/LawSuiteEE-ejb_jar/_LawSuiteEE-ejbPU.server|_ThreadID=32;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|JMX MBeanServer in use: [com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.DynamicInterceptor@50d420eb] from index [0] |#]

[#|2012-04-23T17:04:51.867+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|org.eclipse.persistence.session.file:/home/nicolas/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/LawSuiteEE/LawSuiteEE-ejb_jar/_LawSuiteEE-ejbPU.server|_ThreadID=32;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|JMX MBeanServer in use: [com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer@6e22f51b] from index [1] |#]

[#|2012-04-23T17:04:51.952+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=32;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB UpdateService: [java:global/LawSuiteEE/LawSuiteEE-ejb/UpdateService, java:global/LawSuiteEE/LawSuiteEE-ejb/UpdateService!ch.lawsuite.services.UpdateService]|#]

[#|2012-04-23T17:04:52.028+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=32;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB UserFacade: [java:global/LawSuiteEE/LawSuiteEE-ejb/UserFacade, java:global/LawSuiteEE/LawSuiteEE-ejb/UserFacade!ch.lawsuite.control.UserFacadeRemote]|#]

[#|2012-04-23T17:04:52.029+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=32;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|EJB5182:Glassfish-specific (Non-portable) JNDI names for EJB UserFacade: [ch.lawsuite.control.UserFacadeRemote, ch.lawsuite.control.UserFacadeRemote#ch.lawsuite.control.UserFacadeRemote]|#]

[#|2012-04-23T17:04:52.076+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=32;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB StatelessBean: [java:global/LawSuiteEE/LawSuiteEE-ejb/StatelessBean!ch.lawsuite.services.StatelessBeanRemote, java:global/LawSuiteEE/LawSuiteEE-ejb/StatelessBean]|#]

[#|2012-04-23T17:04:52.076+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=32;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|EJB5182:Glassfish-specific (Non-portable) JNDI names for EJB StatelessBean: [ch.lawsuite.services.StatelessBeanRemote, ch.lawsuite.services.StatelessBeanRemote#ch.lawsuite.services.StatelessBeanRemote]|#]

[#|2012-04-23T17:04:52.109+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers.builder|_ThreadID=32;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|TopLevel AvailabilityService.getAvailabilityEnabled => true|#]

[#|2012-04-23T17:04:52.109+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers.builder|_ThreadID=32;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|TopLevel EjbAvailabilityService.getAvailabilityEnabled => true|#]

[#|2012-04-23T17:04:52.110+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers.builder|_ThreadID=32;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|**Global AvailabilityEnabled => true; isAppHAEnabled: false|#]

[#|2012-04-23T17:04:52.110+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers.builder|_ThreadID=32;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|StatefulContainerBuilder AvailabilityEnabled for this app => false|#]

[#|2012-04-23T17:04:52.110+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers.builder|_ThreadID=32;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|StatefulContainerBuilder.buildStoreManager() storeName: StatefulBean-87503047946665985-BackingStore|#]

[#|2012-04-23T17:04:52.111+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.file.FileBackingStore|_ThreadID=32;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|[FileBackingStore::initialize] Successfully Created and initialized store. Working dir: /home/nicolas/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/session-store/StatefulBean-87503047946665985; Configuration: BackingStoreConfiguration{clusterName='null', instanceName='null', storeName='StatefulBean-87503047946665985-BackingStore', shortUniqueName='87503047946665985', storeType='file', maxIdleTimeInSeconds=-1, relaxVersionCheck='null', maxLoadWaitTimeInSeconds=0, baseDirectoryName='/home/nicolas/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/session-store/StatefulBean-87503047946665985', keyClazz=interface java.io.Serializable, valueClazz=class org.glassfish.ha.store.util.SimpleMetadata, synchronousSave=false, typicalPayloadSizeInKiloBytes=0, vendorSpecificSettings={start.gms=false, async.replication=true, key.transformer=com.sun.ejb.base.sfsb.util.SimpleKeyGenerator@75e09c92, local.caching=true, value.class.is.thread.safe=true, broadcast.remove.expired=false}}|#]

[#|2012-04-23T17:04:52.111+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers.builder|_ThreadID=32;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|StatefulContainerbuilder instantiated store: org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.file.FileBackingStore@6d4771b3; ha-enabled: false ==> BackingStoreConfiguration{clusterName='null', instanceName='null', storeName='StatefulBean-87503047946665985-BackingStore', shortUniqueName='87503047946665985', storeType='file', maxIdleTimeInSeconds=-1, relaxVersionCheck='null', maxLoadWaitTimeInSeconds=0, baseDirectoryName='/home/nicolas/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/session-store/StatefulBean-87503047946665985', keyClazz=interface java.io.Serializable, valueClazz=class org.glassfish.ha.store.util.SimpleMetadata, synchronousSave=false, typicalPayloadSizeInKiloBytes=0, vendorSpecificSettings={start.gms=false, async.replication=true, key.transformer=com.sun.ejb.base.sfsb.util.SimpleKeyGenerator@75e09c92, local.caching=true, value.class.is.thread.safe=true, broadcast.remove.expired=false}}|#]

[#|2012-04-23T17:04:52.127+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=32;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB StatefulBean: [java:global/LawSuiteEE/LawSuiteEE-ejb/StatefulBean, java:global/LawSuiteEE/LawSuiteEE-ejb/StatefulBean!ch.lawsuite.services.StatefulBeanRemote]|#]

[#|2012-04-23T17:04:52.128+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=32;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|EJB5182:Glassfish-specific (Non-portable) JNDI names for EJB StatefulBean: [ch.lawsuite.services.StatefulBeanRemote#ch.lawsuite.services.StatefulBeanRemote, ch.lawsuite.services.StatefulBeanRemote]|#]

[#|2012-04-23T17:04:52.194+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=32;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB AdressFacade: [java:global/LawSuiteEE/LawSuiteEE-ejb/AdressFacade, java:global/LawSuiteEE/LawSuiteEE-ejb/AdressFacade!ch.lawsuite.control.AdressFacadeRemote]|#]

[#|2012-04-23T17:04:52.194+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=32;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|EJB5182:Glassfish-specific (Non-portable) JNDI names for EJB AdressFacade: [ch.lawsuite.control.AdressFacadeRemote#ch.lawsuite.control.AdressFacadeRemote, ch.lawsuite.control.AdressFacadeRemote]|#]

[#|2012-04-23T17:04:52.430+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.org.glassfish.deployment.admin|_ThreadID=32;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|LawSuiteEE was successfully deployed in 661 milliseconds.|#]

[#|2012-04-23T17:06:54.436+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.eclipse.persistence.session.file:/home/nicolas/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/LawSuiteEE/LawSuiteEE-ejb_jar/_LawSuiteEE-ejbPU|_ThreadID=33;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|file:/home/nicolas/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/LawSuiteEE/LawSuiteEE-ejb_jar/_LawSuiteEE-ejbPU logout successful|#]

[#|2012-04-23T17:08:10.014+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.eclipse.persistence.session.file:/home/nicolas/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/LawSuiteEE/LawSuiteEE-ejb_jar/_LawSuiteEE-ejbPU|_ThreadID=19;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461|#]

[#|2012-04-23T17:08:10.015+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.eclipse.persistence.session.file:/home/nicolas/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/LawSuiteEE/LawSuiteEE-ejb_jar/_LawSuiteEE-ejbPU|_ThreadID=19;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|file:/home/nicolas/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/LawSuiteEE/LawSuiteEE-ejb_jar/_LawSuiteEE-ejbPU login successful|#]

 [#|2012-04-23T17:08:10.016+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|org.eclipse.persistence.session.file:/home/nicolas/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/LawSuiteEE/LawSuiteEE-ejb_jar/_LawSuiteEE-ejbPU.server|_ThreadID=19;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Multiple [2] JMX MBeanServer instances exist, we will use the server at index [0] : [com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.DynamicInterceptor@50d420eb].|#]

[#|2012-04-23T17:08:10.016+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|org.eclipse.persistence.session.file:/home/nicolas/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/LawSuiteEE/LawSuiteEE-ejb_jar/_LawSuiteEE-ejbPU.server|_ThreadID=19;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|JMX MBeanServer in use: [com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.DynamicInterceptor@50d420eb] from index [0] |#]

[#|2012-04-23T17:08:10.016+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|org.eclipse.persistence.session.file:/home/nicolas/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/LawSuiteEE/LawSuiteEE-ejb_jar/_LawSuiteEE-ejbPU.server|_ThreadID=19;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|JMX MBeanServer in use: [com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer@6e22f51b] from index [1] |#]

[#|2012-04-23T17:08:10.099+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers.builder|_ThreadID=19;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|TopLevel AvailabilityService.getAvailabilityEnabled => true|#]

[#|2012-04-23T17:08:10.100+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers.builder|_ThreadID=19;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|TopLevel EjbAvailabilityService.getAvailabilityEnabled => true|#]

[#|2012-04-23T17:08:10.100+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers.builder|_ThreadID=19;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|**Global AvailabilityEnabled => true; isAppHAEnabled: false|#]

[#|2012-04-23T17:08:10.100+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers.builder|_ThreadID=19;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|StatefulContainerBuilder AvailabilityEnabled for this app => false|#]

[#|2012-04-23T17:08:10.101+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers.builder|_ThreadID=19;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|StatefulContainerBuilder.buildStoreManager() storeName: StatefulBean-87503047946731521-BackingStore|#]

[#|2012-04-23T17:08:10.102+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.file.FileBackingStore|_ThreadID=19;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|[FileBackingStore::initialize] Successfully Created and initialized store. Working dir: /home/nicolas/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/session-store/StatefulBean-87503047946731521; Configuration: BackingStoreConfiguration{clusterName='null', instanceName='null', storeName='StatefulBean-87503047946731521-BackingStore', shortUniqueName='87503047946731521', storeType='file', maxIdleTimeInSeconds=-1, relaxVersionCheck='null', maxLoadWaitTimeInSeconds=0, baseDirectoryName='/home/nicolas/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/session-store/StatefulBean-87503047946731521', keyClazz=interface java.io.Serializable, valueClazz=class org.glassfish.ha.store.util.SimpleMetadata, synchronousSave=false, typicalPayloadSizeInKiloBytes=0, vendorSpecificSettings={start.gms=false, async.replication=true, key.transformer=com.sun.ejb.base.sfsb.util.SimpleKeyGenerator@7cfa3f14, local.caching=true, value.class.is.thread.safe=true, broadcast.remove.expired=false}}|#]

 [#|2012-04-23T17:08:10.102+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers.builder|_ThreadID=19;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|StatefulContainerbuilder instantiated store: org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.file.FileBackingStore@11437a26; ha-enabled: false ==> BackingStoreConfiguration{clusterName='null', instanceName='null', storeName='StatefulBean-87503047946731521-BackingStore', shortUniqueName='87503047946731521', storeType='file', maxIdleTimeInSeconds=-1, relaxVersionCheck='null', maxLoadWaitTimeInSeconds=0, baseDirectoryName='/home/nicolas/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/session-store/StatefulBean-87503047946731521', keyClazz=interface java.io.Serializable, valueClazz=class org.glassfish.ha.store.util.SimpleMetadata, synchronousSave=false, typicalPayloadSizeInKiloBytes=0, vendorSpecificSettings={start.gms=false, async.replication=true, key.transformer=com.sun.ejb.base.sfsb.util.SimpleKeyGenerator@7cfa3f14, local.caching=true, value.class.is.thread.safe=true, broadcast.remove.expired=false}}|#]

[#|2012-04-23T17:08:10.133+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=19;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB StatefulBean: [java:global/LawSuiteEE/LawSuiteEE-ejb/StatefulBean, java:global/LawSuiteEE/LawSuiteEE-ejb/StatefulBean!ch.lawsuite.services.StatefulBeanRemote]|#]

[#|2012-04-23T17:08:10.134+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=19;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|EJB5182:Glassfish-specific (Non-portable) JNDI names for EJB StatefulBean: [ch.lawsuite.services.StatefulBeanRemote#ch.lawsuite.services.StatefulBeanRemote, ch.lawsuite.services.StatefulBeanRemote]|#]

[#|2012-04-23T17:08:10.168+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=19;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB StatelessBean: [java:global/LawSuiteEE/LawSuiteEE-ejb/StatelessBean!ch.lawsuite.services.StatelessBeanRemote, java:global/LawSuiteEE/LawSuiteEE-ejb/StatelessBean]|#]

[#|2012-04-23T17:08:10.168+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=19;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|EJB5182:Glassfish-specific (Non-portable) JNDI names for EJB StatelessBean: [ch.lawsuite.services.StatelessBeanRemote, ch.lawsuite.services.StatelessBeanRemote#ch.lawsuite.services.StatelessBeanRemote]|#]

[#|2012-04-23T17:08:10.183+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=19;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB UpdateService: [java:global/LawSuiteEE/LawSuiteEE-ejb/UpdateService, java:global/LawSuiteEE/LawSuiteEE-ejb/UpdateService!ch.lawsuite.services.UpdateService]|#]

[#|2012-04-23T17:08:10.240+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=19;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB UserFacade: [java:global/LawSuiteEE/LawSuiteEE-ejb/UserFacade, java:global/LawSuiteEE/LawSuiteEE-ejb/UserFacade!ch.lawsuite.control.UserFacadeRemote]|#]

[#|2012-04-23T17:08:10.240+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=19;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|EJB5182:Glassfish-specific (Non-portable) JNDI names for EJB UserFacade: [ch.lawsuite.control.UserFacadeRemote, ch.lawsuite.control.UserFacadeRemote#ch.lawsuite.control.UserFacadeRemote]|#]

[#|2012-04-23T17:08:10.303+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=19;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB AdressFacade: [java:global/LawSuiteEE/LawSuiteEE-ejb/AdressFacade, java:global/LawSuiteEE/LawSuiteEE-ejb/AdressFacade!ch.lawsuite.control.AdressFacadeRemote]|#]

[#|2012-04-23T17:08:10.303+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=19;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|EJB5182:Glassfish-specific (Non-portable) JNDI names for EJB AdressFacade: [ch.lawsuite.control.AdressFacadeRemote#ch.lawsuite.control.AdressFacadeRemote, ch.lawsuite.control.AdressFacadeRemote]|#]

[#|2012-04-23T17:08:10.515+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.org.glassfish.deployment.admin|_ThreadID=19;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|LawSuiteEE was successfully deployed in 591 milliseconds.|#]

[#|2012-04-23T17:10:33.388+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.com.sun.enterprise.container.common|_ThreadID=34;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|User [] from host localhost does not have administration access|#]

[#|2012-04-23T17:10:35.050+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.admingui|_ThreadID=31;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Admin Console: Initializing Session Attributes...|#]
```

Comment: Are all your DNS servers reachable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are running really untipical EJB, it should not (I use it every day without problem).
So I will make a stupid answer:
Check:

1. Your lan
2. Your remote machine load (idle/busy)
3. Your firewall

Comment: I have installed my server on another machine (4GB RAM) and have set Xmx2048m and Xms1024m. iptables totally revised and also tried to switch of the firewall temporarly. there's only glassfish and mysql running on the server. throughput of LAN is up to 92mbit/sec. Any further ideas ?

Comment: How slow is slow?  This bug shows that there are problems in that general area:  http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-16560

Another thing you could look at is upload the file to the server yourself, then use the admin GUI to deploy it from there using the "local packaged file".  Then tail the server log to see just how long the deploy takes that way.

Comment: @.TPete: log file attached. @.Jim: Roughly 3 min. Tried the same with Ubuntu Server Edition x64. Same problem. Also tried to run Glassfish on Windows 7, there it's no problem -> deployed from Netbeans within approx. 5 seconds. Any ideas ?

Comment: @.TPete: Okay I imported/deployed my *.ear file directly by using the web-admin-interface. This was really fast..! Do you have any clue how I could solve the problem with Netbeans ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Netbeans does a different style of deployment, like an exploded directory.  You could try something else to do the deploy.  Are you using maven or the netbeans default build (ant)?  Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836317/which-maven-glassfish-plugin-to-use) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635861/best-way-to-deploy-on-glassfish-v3).  Personally, NB 7.1.1 takes a minute to deploy my app, but it's still fast enough.