# Deployment of a web project to Glassfish via ANT in Java for all platforms

Tags: java, deployment, ant, glassfish, cross-platform

I have a web project that deploys war files, and right now I can deploy to Glassfish in Windows. Here is my build.xml's necessary part.

```
<target
    name="deploywar" 
    description="Varolan WAR dosyasını yayınlar." >
    <echo level="info" >
        Proje sunucuda yayinlaniyor... 
    </echo>
    <exec
        executable="cmd"
        failonerror="true"
        output="${out.txt}" >
        <arg value="/c" />
        <arg value="${glassfish.path}/glassfish/bin/asadmin --passwordfile ${password.file} deploy --contextroot /GlassfishDeployment ${deployyolu}/${war.filename}" />
    </exec>
</target>
```

BUT I want to re-write my code to work on all platforms. I did some searchs about it which ends up with [this helpful page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1752/beaep/). I wanted to try this method. I added necessary Jar file in to my project. Then I did these task definitions ;

```
<fileset dir="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib">
<include name="sun-appserv-ant.jar"/>
</fileset>

<target name="as-ant-init">
<taskdef name="sun-appserv-deploy"
  classname="org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.sun.appserv.DeployTask" />
<taskdef name="sun-appserv-undeploy"
  classname="org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.sun.appserv.UndeployTask" />
<taskdef name="sun-appserv-component"
  classname="org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.sun.appserv.ComponentTask" />
<taskdef name="sun-appserv-admin"
  classname="org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.sun.appserv.AdminTask" />
<taskdef name="sun-appserv-jspc"
  classname="org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.sun.appserv.SunJspc" />
<taskdef name="sun-appserv-update"
  classname="org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.sun.appserv.UpdateTask" />
<taskdef name="sun-appserv-instance"
  classname="org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.sun.appserv.InstanceTask" />
 <taskdef name="wsgen" classname="com.sun.tools.ws.ant.WsGen" />
 <taskdef name="wsimport" classname="com.sun.tools.ws.ant.WsImport" />
<classpath path="${glassfish.path}/lib/sun-appserv-ant.jar" />
</target>
```

I ended up with this error;

```
taskdef class org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.sun.appserv.DeployTask cannot be found
```

Could anyone help me about solving this error or another way to deploy w/o platform?
Thanks.

Comment: you need to tell `<taskdef>` which `<classpath>` it should use to look for the class...

Comment: I already did it on target, it didn't work. I took classpath definition in to taskdef definition, it didn't work either.

Comment: I mean, by your example, you need to declare the `classpath` before any of the `taskdef` and give the `classpath` an ID; then use `classpathref="classpathid"` in `taskdef`s. Anything in this page applies to `taskdef`: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/typedef.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used this code fragment from this reply ;

```
<presetdef name="asadmin">
  <java jar="${glassfish.home}/modules/admin-cli.jar" fork="true" jvm="${java.home}/bin/java" >
    <arg line="--port ${glassfish.admin.port}" />
  </java>
</presetdef>
<target name="deploy">
  <asadmin failonerror="true">
    <arg value="deploy" />
    <arg value="--force=true" />
    <arg value="${ear.file}" />
  </asadmin>
</target>
```

It solved my problem. 
Thanks to;
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7299637/1400515