# how to deploy to Glassfish with Gradle?

Tags: gradle, deployment, glassfish, ejb, ear

How does Gradle deploy to Glassfish?

Ant [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7299637/262852):

```
<target name="deploy"
    description="deploys application to glassfish">
    <exec failonerror="true" executable="cmd">
     <arg value="/c" />
     <arg value="asadmin --user ${gfUser} --passwordfile ${gfPassFile} --host ${host} deploy build/${war}" />
    </exec>
</target>
```

Yes, I *could* use `asadmin` but doing so from Gradle would be so much more Groovy.